# Reduce number of elements returned by lapply

Tags: r, list, lapply

As `?lapply` states:

> lapply returns a list of the same length as X, each element of which
>   is the result of applying FUN to the corresponding element of X.

Is it still possible to return a list with a smaller length than X?

#### Code

```
l <- lapply(1:10,function(u)ifelse(u<5,return(u),return(NULL)))
```

Can I place something in the return(NULL) part in order to drop/omit the element completely?

#### Desired Output

Output of the code section should be the same as:

```
l[!sapply(l,is.null)]
```

a list of 4 with only elements smaller 5!

Comment: You can look the `purrr` package from the tidyverse, and the function `compact` in particular

Comment: If you're hoping to return a vector, then wrapping the call in `unlist` will convert to vector and implicitly drop any NULL elements.

Comment: You could obviously write a custom wrapper like `FUN <- function(...){
  purrr::compact(lapply(...))
}`

Comment: Doesn't the description you quote answer your question very clearly?

Comment: `lapply` will always return a result the same length as the input but you could use `Filter(Negate(is.null), lapply(...))` to return the non-null results.

Comment: You can also do `Filter(length, lapply(1:10,function(u)ifelse(u<5,return(u),return(NULL))))`

Comment: `Filter(length, lapply(...))` will work in ordinary cases but note that it will also remove zero length components that are not NULL such as `character(0)`.

Comment: @docendodiscimus It does in my opinion not exclude the possibility of an existence of any workaround.

Comment: Voting to close, as question is not "How to remove NULLs **after** lapply?" (then this is a duplicate) but "Is it possible to return smaller length output from input length **within** lapply?" (from manuals: it says no)

Comment: You can pre-filter too of course. Assuming you like pipes... `library(magrittr); (1:10) %>% Filter(f = . %>% is_less_than(5)) %>% lapply(. %>% add(1))` or... `library(data.table); data.table(x = 1:10)[x < 5, x + 1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it still possible to return a list with a smaller length than X?

Per the documentation quoted by the OP, the answer is "no, not unless you wrap `lapply` in another call that filters out the unwanted elements either before or after it."

---

There are many possible workarounds, but I might do ...

```
# example function
f = function(z) c(a = list(z+1), b = list(z-1), c = if (z > 3) list(z^2))

library(data.table)
data.table(x = 1:10)[x < 5, rbindlist(lapply(x, f), fill=TRUE)]

   a b  c
1: 2 0 NA
2: 3 1 NA
3: 4 2 NA
4: 5 3 16
```

... assuming the function returns a named list. If it just returns a scalar, try vectorizing or using `sapply` or `vapply` instead of `lapply`.

Comment: If you all agree on that the statement in the manual excludes such desired output, I might have asked a stupid question ;-). But for someone having the same thoughts, this question might be a good reference. Best regards.